# Good Introduction / Tutorial to Mathematica **Books**

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)

I'm a high school senior and am using Mathematica for a research project. However, I find it a bit slow to learn Mathematica by watching videos.
I know that there are many helpful videos of Mathematica topics online, but I was wondering if there are any books or reference manuals I can read offline.

I've looked at the question at

[What is the best Mathematica tutorial for young people?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/733/what-is-the-best-mathematica-tutorial-for-young-people)

But again, it only lists online resources.

So are there are any books out there detailing an introduction to Mathematica?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [mathematica.se]! Your question was previously asked here and there are a lot (a lot!) of references of different kinds for all programmer levels in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/5). It should keep you busy for a while :)

Comment: Thank you for that incredible resource!!!