# Where can I learn to use mathematica comprehensively?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've heard great things about all the wonders and capabilities of mathematica. I've had the software for sometime now, but all I know how to do are simple calculations and stuff shown in the hands on tutorial on the mathematica site.

I've looked around the Web, and all I could find are some scattered tutorials, outdated books, and tips here and there on how to do stuff.

My question is: is there a comprehensive site / book / documentation file that teaches the ins and outs of how to use the software, and do all these amazing things the promotional videos say they can do? The sample projects on the website shows what others have done, but doesn't explain them comprehensively enough.

Please mathematica pros, guide me.

Thanks!

P. S. I'm a Mathematics University student.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I believe this has been asked before in question [11530](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11530) and marked as a duplicate of question [18](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18).

Comment: Sure, I'll keep them in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I'm not looking for tutorials, but a comprehensive way to learn the entire system.

Comment: For example, if I'm a Calculus student, I want a Calculus textbook, not tutorials on integration.

Comment: `comprehensive way to learn the entire system` I believe this is impossible to do. Mathematica is too large and complicated to be learned fully and comprehensively in one life time by any one. You could learn parts of it well may be, but not the whole system. I do not think there any one person living who have used all of Mathematica commands for example. (well, may be MrWizard did) but I mean for the rest of us, this is impossible task.

Comment: Is that so? Hard to believe that a software that's only a couple decades old could be so expansive.

Comment: [What Mathematica book to buy?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/what-mathematica-book-to-buy)

Comment: Is programming in mathematica the same as using it to perform calculations and analysis? Or is Proud

Comment: ... Or is programming mathematica a sort of software engineering like programming in C?