# Changing Values in an Association using Map

Tags: expression-manipulation, associations, assignment, guidelines, faq

I am trying to change the value of one key in an association based on the value of another key in that association. So if my association starts as:

```
x=<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>
```

I want to change it to:

```
<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>
```

So I wrote the function:

```
f[x_] := If[x[["firstValue"]], x[["isFirstValueTrue"]] = True, x[["isFirstValueTrue"]] = False]
```

I got an error, but based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875913/setsetps-in-the-part-assignment-is-not-a-symbol I was to correct it by using`SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]`

But let's say I want to do this to a list of associations:

```
    x={<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
     <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
     <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
     <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>}
```

so I wrote

```
Map[f[#] &, x]
```

However, the "in the part assignment is not a symbol." error appears again and you can't `SetAttributes[Map, HoldAll]`. I realize I can make a copy of the list and make changes to that, but the actual list I'm working with is much larger so I do not want to do that. The third solution in the link above is able to be mapped, but it doesn't seem like you can replace in an association. Any suggestions?

Comment: As @LeonidShifrin points out, the problem is immutability instead of lack of `HoldAll` attribute of map. But just in case you need to hold the input for functions without hold attribute, you can use `Map[f, Unevaluated@x]`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Preamble

This is a very good question, because answering it will make it very clear what immutability means, both in general and in the context of `Association`s.

### General

#### A few general words on immutability

Associations are immutable data structures. This means that they carry no state, and a copy of an `Association` is another completely independent `Association`.  This is similar to Lists in Mathematica, but while List copying is expensive (when, for example, it is not just copying but some, however small, modification), the copying / making small modifications to Associations is cheap. In particular,

```
Append[lst, elem]
```

will have the complexity proportional to `Length[lst]`, while

```
Append[assoc, key -> value]
```

will be roughly constant time. Again, in both cases the result is a new independent data structure carrying no state. But while iterative accumulation of lists isn't practical, iterative accumulation of Associations is (top-level iteration overhead notwithstanding), precisely due to the above complexity arguments.

Because immutable structures have no internal state (at least as far as the end user is concerned), their identity is completely defined by their structure. You can't change an immutable structure without changing its identity, i.e. without producing a new, different structure. This is in contrast to mutable structs or objects, which formally preserve their identity (reference, place in memory where the reference points to) even when they are internally changed. For example, in Java, if you write

```
 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("first","firstValue");
```

and then execute

```
 map.put("second","secondValue")
```

then the state of the object has changed, but it remained the same object in terms of its identity (can be accessed via the same reference), etc. This also means that if you use such an object in several places in your program, and change it in one place, it will also be "felt" in all other places, since all of them actually point to the same object.

But when you modify an `Association`, you get a brand new `Association`, which is a *different* object. So, looking at it from this angle, we can see that the core difference between mutable and immutable data structures is in their approach to identity: mutable structures define identity via the reference to the object (place in memory, etc), but *not* its content. For the above Java example, this is reflected by the necessity to define methods `equals` and `hashCode` in a mutually consistent way, to be able to use an object as a key in a hash map. For the same reason, in Python you can't use lists as keys in dictionaries (lists are mutable, and therefore don't preserve their structural identity over time), but can use special data structures like tuples and frozen sets (which are immutable).

Immutable data structures OTOH directly associate their identity with their internal (user-level) structure, and don't care about references, memory locations, etc. The code that uses immutable structures tends to be more modular and easier to argue about and debug, because immutable structures, being stateless, don't depend on the environment. This automatically makes functions using them more composable, and also individually testable. Not all problems are easily amenable to immutable data structures, but many are, particularly those related to complicated data transformations.

#### Complications

Immutable structures are nice, but in many cases using them in their pure form would be impractical. In particular, one of the most common needs is to be able to mutate (change) some specific elements in a list, without copying the entire list. The main reason to need this is, of course, efficiency.

So, Lists in Mathematica are given a limited form of mutability: if you assign a list to a `Symbol`, then you *can* mutate its elements in-place. In fact, this is true for general expressions, and on arbitrary level (elements at any depth), not just lists. Strictly speaking, this does not really make lists or general expressions mutable - because there are no references, but rather constructs a more efficient short-cut to an operation like

```
var  = doSomethingWithSomePartOf[var]
```

In other words, I think that the right way to think about this mutability is that the resulting contents of a given variable is a *different* list (expression), but there is a syntax to perform part replacements efficiently, de-facto changing elements in place. This doesn't change the overall programming model of Mathematica, which is based on immutable expressions and the absence of explicit references - it just makes certain specific (part) modifications efficient when done in-place for structures assigned to Symbols.

What is peculiar about this capability is that it can only be achieved via the `Part` command (and a few overloaded functions such as `AddTo`, `AppendTo`, etc.), and only if the argument of `Part` is a `Symbol`. In other words, there doesn't exist general reference / pointer semantics in Mathematica, but rather a very limited form of it, the minimal form necessary to provide mutability. What this means is that while you can mutate some List (or general expression), like

```
lst = Partition[Range[10],2]
lst[[2,1]] = 100
```

You can't do this in two steps like

```
With[{part = lst[[2]]}, part[[1]] = 200]
```

> During evaluation of In[27]:= Set::setps: {100,4} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

```
(* 200  *)
```

because `lst[[2]]` is not by itself an L-value that can be assigned - it evaluates to an immutable value which can't be further assigned. So, what we have here is certain form of mutability without actual pass-by-reference mechanism. Note by the way that this works:

```
lst[[2]][[1]] = 200

200
```

But not because there are general references, but because `Part` has been specially overloaded.

The same story happens with Associations. They too have been given some form of mutability, similar to Lists. If we start with your example:

```
x = 
 {<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>, 
  <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>, 
  <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>, 
  <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>}
```

Then, using

```
xcopy = x;
```

We can see that this will work:

```
xcopy[[1, Key["isFirstValueTrue"]]] = xcopy[[1, Key["firstValue"]]]

(* True *)
```

But for Associations, this doesn't:

```
xcopy[[1]]["isFirstValueTrue"] = xcopy[[1]]["firstValue"]
```

> During evaluation of In[45]:= Association::setps: <|firstValue->True,isFirstValueTrue->True|> in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

```
(* True *)
```

What works here is:

```
xcopy[[1]][[Key["isFirstValueTrue"]]] = xcopy[[1]]["firstValue"]

(* True *)
```

It may well be that at some later point the first form will also be made to work.

#### The role of Hold - attributes

It is important to clarify the role of `Hold`-attributes in this context. We know that, if we want to pass some argument by reference, we need to set the appropriate `Hold` attribute. A simplest example here would be writing our own `Increment` function:

```
ClearAll[increment];
SetAttributes[increment, HoldFirst]
increment[x_]:=x=x+1;
```

There are two things which I think are important to realize here. One is that `Hold`- attributes carry out a much more general task in Mathematica: they allow one to modify the evaluation process and work with unevaluated code blocks (pass them around, delay their evaluation, analyze them, etc). Their role in providing a pass-by-reference semantics is a very special case of their general functionality.

The second thing to note here is that Hold-attributes in fact don't provide a full pass-by-reference mechanism. They can't, because there are no references in Mathematica. By a reference, I mean here a handle, which can exist in between evaluations, while providing a way to mutate an object it points to. Symbols by themselves can't serve as references, because they evaluate immediately, once allowed to. One can certainly emulate references with the top-level Mathematica code, but the point here is that they are not natively present in the core computational model in Mathematica (and that would mean tight integration with the language and its many constructs).

The way Hold-attributes work is by delaying evaluation of expressions until they are substituted verbatim into the body of the functions, to which they get passed. This is possible because parameter-passing semantics in Mathematica makes pretty much all functions work like macros, which assemble their bodies before executing them. The reason this is not a true pass by reference semantics is that the property of delayed evaluation is attached not to arguments being passed (which would make them true references), but to certain functions we pass those argument to. And this is exactly the reason why this style of programming is hard in Mathematica: if we pass arguments through the chain of functions, we have to explicitly make sure that they will be preserved unevaluated by all intermediate functions in the chain. In practice, this is too much hassle to be worth it, in all cases except a few.

### The case at hand

#### Mutable approach

In any case, given your particular problem, one way to solve it would be:

```
xcopy = x;
xcopy[[All, Key["isFirstValueTrue"]]] = xcopy[[All, Key["firstValue"]]];
xcopy
```

(you could've used `x` instead of `xcopy` - I maintain a copy to preserve `x` unchanged, because I am using it here several times).

The above considerations also tell us that this will work:

```
ClearAll[setFV];
SetAttributes[setFV, HoldAll];
setFV[x_?ListQ] := Map[setFV[x[[#]]] &, Range[Length[x]]];
setFV[x_?AssociationQ] := x[[Key["isFirstValueTrue"]]] = x["firstValue"];
```

So that you can also do:

```
xcopy = x;
setFV[xcopy];
xcopy
```

However, already here one can notice that we start to swim upstream. In particular, we must pay careful attention to preserve certain parts in held form (for reasons I outlined above, so that they can kind of serve as references), and there are subtle things here, which, if changed slightly, will break this code. For example, if I used patterns `_List` and `_Association` in place of `_?ListQ` and `_?AssociationQ`, this wouldn't work.

Even for lists, such mutable approach is rarely worth using (except in massive assignments at the same time), and for Associations, this is even more so, because, in contrast with Lists, they are cheap to modify element-wise.

#### A better approach

A much better approach, in my view, is to embrace immutability. In this particular case, this would mean using something like:

```
xcopy = x;
xcopy = Map[
  Function[assoc,
    MapAt[assoc["firstValue"] &, assoc, {Key["isFirstValueTrue"]}]
  ]
]@ xcopy
```

which is, perform operations on immutable data, and assign the result to the initial variable.

### Conclusions

Because Mathematica adds a limited form of mutability to otherwise immutable data structures, but lacks the general reference / pointer semantics, mutable code is rarely the best approach (it does have its uses though). Very often, it may be better to use a generally more idiomatic approach based on transforming immutable structures. This may be particularly true for Associations, which are cheap to modify.

Comment: I realize now that I simplified my problem a bit too much by asking to change the second value to the first value. A more accurate example of my problem would've been where the first value is some number and the second value is the boolean of whether the first is greater than 5. Not that I'm complaining at all, haha. Thank you for your very in depth answer. This helps a lot. And since I was partly asking the question to get a better understanding of association and the whole hold thing, this proved to be especially useful.

Answer (score 33):

I hesitate to add anything after @Leonid's comprehensive answer, but I'd like to point out that an easy way to achieve the stated goal is to define `f` like this:

```
f[x_] := <| x, "isFirstValueTrue" -> x@"firstValue" |>
```

... which yields the desired result when mapped across the associations in `x`:

```
f /@ x
(* { <|"firstValue" -> True,  "isFirstValueTrue" -> True |>,
     <|"firstValue" -> True,  "isFirstValueTrue" -> True |>,
     <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
     <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|> } *)
```

This technique can be used to incrementally update multiple fields in an association, or even to add new fields:

```
f2[x_] := <| x, "isFirstValueTrue" -> x@"firstValue", "old" -> x@"isFirstValueTrue" |>

f2 /@ x
(* { <|firstValue -> True,  isFirstValueTrue -> True,  old -> False|>,
     <|firstValue -> True,  isFirstValueTrue -> True,  old -> True |>,
     <|firstValue -> False, isFirstValueTrue -> False, old -> False|>,
     <|firstValue -> False, isFirstValueTrue -> False, old -> True |> } *)
```

See [How can I add a column into a existing Dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51473/142) for discussion of this construction (called the "shorter form" in that answer).

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I *discovered* that an association enclosed by a left and right association bracket (e.g. `<| <|"a" -> x, "b" -> y|>|>`) collapses into a single association (e.g., `<|"a" -> x, "b" -> y|>`). I can't find any mention of this in the documentation. I think that you might mention this in your answer.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I agree that the documentation should give an explicit example of this construction.  I have discussed this issue in comments and chat a few times, but you are right it belongs somewhere on the main site.  I have added some discussion to an answer elsewhere and linked to it in this response.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 12):

This question is done and dusted but it is such a good one (together with the existing answers) for demonstrating and encapsulating the different ways `Association`s can be modified, that I'd like to belatedly summarise while suggesting some other takeaways. In particular, how it can further highlight a mutable and immutable dichotomy or perhaps more accurately, a potential synergy.

**The OP's attempt:**

The initial OP attempt for a single association

```
x = <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>;
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x_] := If[x[["firstValue"]], x[["isFirstValueTrue"]] = True, x[["isFirstValueTrue"]] = False];
f@x;
x

(* <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>*)
```

works as intended because modifying a component is performed using a named variable within `Part` in a similar vein to the way in which such modifications are performed in `List`s

```
ls = {1, 2, 3};
ls[[2]] = 0.5; 
ls
(* {1, 0.5, 3} *)
```

In lists however, `Set` cannot use `Part` without a named variable:

```
{1, 2, 3}[[2]] = 0.5

Set::setps: {1,2,3} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
```

The same principle applies to `Association`s as was observed by the OP when applying `f` to `xx`'s individual associations (note `xx` is used here to denote multiple associations instead of the original `x`)

```
xx = {
   <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
   <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
   <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
   <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>
   };

f /@ xx

Set::setps: <|firstValue->True,isFirstValueTrue->False|> in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
```

This suggests a way of rescuing this idiomatic attempt by explicitly naming `xx`'s elements. Suppose for example, the following are/were defined:

```
x1 = <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>;
x2 = <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>;
x3 = <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>;
x4 = <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>;

xx = Hold@{x1, x2, x3, x4};
```

in which case `f` *can* now be applied to the constituent `Association`s since they can now be symbolically referenced:

```
Map[f, xx, {2}] // ReleaseHold

(* {True, True, False, False} *)
```

and after releasing we get the required transformation of `xx`.

```
xx // ReleaseHold

 (*
 {
<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
<|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
<|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>
}
*)
```

Note that in this mutable approach, `AssociateTo` could have been used to perhaps add readability

```
f[x_] := AssociateTo[x, "isFirstValueTrue" -> x@"firstValue"]
```

but at any rate, this "solution" is clearly unwieldy not only from the point of view of having to alternate between `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` but also from introducing subsidiary, symbolic definitions, `x1, ..., x4`. This was alluded to in Leonid Shifron's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations) to another question describing the advantages of immutability since in certain contexts ...

> ...  should you use symbols / their `DownValues`, you'd have to generate
>   new symbols and then manage them - monitor when they are no longer
>   needed and release them. This is a pain in the neck ...

Hence in this case, removing `xx` doesn't automatically remove `x1, ..., x4` (here `OwnValues` but the same principle applies) while conversely, removing any of `x1, ..., x4` changes `xx`, something not necessarily expected or desired.

The great thing about the introduction of `Association`s however, is that by infusing immutability no such artifice is needed or future surprises likely as all the bookkeeping is handled automatically behind the scenes.

Several solutions were provided in the other responses each of which is now recast with `Query` equivalents together with `MyReplacePart`, `MyReplacePartFix` that forms the basis of these answers' immutable/mutable approaches. All of the following solutions use the `xx` definition which is restored as needed (in the mutable approaches):

```
SetAttributes[Restore, HoldAll];
Restore[xx_] := xx = {
    <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
    <|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
    <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
    <|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>
    };
Restore@xx;
```

and all solutions generate the following output (or a visual equivalent as in solution 7):

```
(*
 {
<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
<|"firstValue" -> True, "isFirstValueTrue" -> True|>,
<|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>,
<|"firstValue" -> False, "isFirstValueTrue" -> False|>
}
*)
```

**Collection of Immutable/Mutable Solutions**

**1. MapAt (Immutable)**

```
MapAt[Function[dummy, #"firstValue"], "isFirstValueTrue"]@# & /@ xx
```

**2. Shadow (Immutable)**

```
(<|#, "isFirstValueTrue" -> #"firstValue"|> & /@ xx)
```

**3. Insert (Immutable)**

```
Insert["isFirstValueTrue" -> #"firstValue", "isFirstValueTrue"]@# & /@ xx
```

**4. QueryMapAt (Immutable)**

```
QueryMapAt = Query[All, MapAt[Function[dummy, #"firstValue"], "isFirstValueTrue"]@# &];
QueryMapAt@xx
```

**5. QueryShadow (Immutable)**

```
QueryShadow = Query[All, <|#, "isFirstValueTrue" -> #"firstValue"|> &];
QueryShadow@xx
```

**6. QueryCreateColumns (Immutable)**

```
QueryCreateColumns = Query[All, <|"firstValue" -> "firstValue", "isFirstValueTrue" -> "firstValue"|>];
QueryCreateColumns@xx
```

**7. Dataset[queryMethod] (Immutable)**

```
xxDataset = Dataset@xx;
queryMethod = RandomChoice[{QueryMapAt, QueryShadow, QueryCreateColumns}];
Row[{xxDataset, " -> ", xxDataset@queryMethod}]
```

[image]

**8. MyReplacePart (Immutable)**

```
C2Query = Query[All, "isFirstValueTrue"];
C1Query = Query[All, "firstValue"];

MyReplacePart[C2Query -> C1Query]@xx

(* definition follows of MyReplacePart *)
```

---

**9. SetPart (Mutable)**

```
 xx[[All, "isFirstValueTrue"]] = xx[[All, "firstValue"]];
 xx
```

**10. QuerySetPart (Mutable)**

```
Restore@xx;
QuerySetPart[C2Query, C1Query]@xx;
xx

(* definition follows of QuerySetPart *)
```

**11. ReplacePartFix (Mutable)**

```
Restore@xx;
ReplacePartFix[C2Query -> C1Query]@xx;
xx

(* definition follows of ReplacePartFix *)
```

**Comments:**

**1.** This is essentially @Leonid's recommended, immutable solution (slightly modified into a keyless operator-form with a dummy variable that simultaneously reflects this inner function's purpose while removing it from the outer function's clutches). It is very general in the sense that `MapAt` can be used in more powerful ways (that does something beyond returning a constant), can be applied to any position, supports the standard "immutable" idiom and represents a way of conceiving operations that IMO is indispensable in effectively working with associations.

On the other hand, perhaps an "immutable, `ReplacePart` intent" or "mutable `ReplacePartFix` intent" more closely capture the OP's original intent.

**2.** This is @WReach's solution and is perhaps the most elegant one for this specific question as it leverages Mathematica's automatic overriding. On the other hand, the overriding conceptually involves a two-step process that perhaps only merits a single step.

**3.** Similar in tone to the previous solution with the insertion overrides the value in two steps.

**4-6** These solutions represent query forms of the previous immutable solutions with `All` essentially replacing `Map`'s operation. It also emphasises that while the `Query` hints at a passive "querying" of a `Dataset`/`Association`'s content, the inclusion of transformative functions as possible operators (i.e. in addition to `Part` specifications) demonstrate their greater power and possibly representing the optimal way to immutably transform datasets. Its advantages are at least threefold: 1) encapsulation for improving code readability 2) harnessing `Dataset`'s functionality 3) Extensibility from subsequent `Query` modification/composition. Of these I regard the last as being the most important (as illustrated shortly).

**7.** Dataset offers its own advantages including a visualisation produced from any of the previous queries.

**8.** In my opinion, this represents the most natural way of implementing the OP's "immutable intent" (i.e. if still in the "experimental or prototyping phase"). It requires first defining `MyReplacePart`

```
MyReplacePart[q1_Query -> new_] := 
  Function[assoc, Module[{temp = assoc}, temp[[Sequence @@ q1]] = new; temp], 
   HoldAll];

MyReplacePart[q1_Query -> q2_Query] := 
  Function[assoc, 
   Module[{temp = assoc}, temp[[Sequence @@ q1]] = q2@assoc; temp], HoldAll];
```

Note:

- This extension implements an operator form via pure functions
  (instead of using `Subvalue` given its `HoldAll` [limitations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues))
- Implementing (an immutable) `MyReplacePart` effectively involves a inefficient, mutable detour through a local, `temp` variable in order to avoid changing existing state. A native implementation would naturally be faster and possibly further enhanced with a post-fix short-form (say  `xx |. C2Query -> C1Query`)
- As characterised by all "immutable implementations", the entire data structure is returned without altering `xx`'s underlying definition. If the OP's intent was instead to alter this underlying definition then all the immutable solutions need a concluding assignment as in: `xx = MyReplacePart[C2Query -> C1Query]@xx`

On the other hand, if the OP's intent was instead to alter the underlying data structure (say following a period of extended experimentation), then this can also be performed mutably which in such a context is, I would argue, the more natural approach and is used in the next three solutions.

**9.** This is @Leonid Shifron's (first) mutable solution using `Part` and `Set` and has the virtue of perhaps most closely following the OP's intent in a "post-experimental" phase with existing built-in functions. It strikes me as a reasonable approach for this situation or indeed any other one in which an individual and isolated change to a large data structure is required.

**10.** Given the previously stated advantages of `Query`, the previous `Part`-`Set` can be similarly cast.

```
QuerySetPart[lhs_, rhs_] := Function[assoc, assoc[[Sequence @@ lhs]] = rhs@assoc, HoldAll];
```

Note also since "mutable" solutions changes `xx`'s underlying definition from now on this needs to be periodically `Restore`d to test new solutions.

**11.** In my opinion, this solution represents the most natural way of implementing the OP's "immutable intent" (i.e. if in the "post-experimental" or "post-prototyping" phase). `MyReplacePartFix` is the mutable version of the immutable `MyReplacePart` since the underlying association, `xx`, is now changed in place (and hence no "conceptual copying" is needed via a `temp` variable).

```
MyReplacePartFix[q1_Query -> new_] := 
  Function[assoc, assoc[[Sequence @@ q1]] = new; assoc, HoldAll];

MyReplacePartFix[q1_Query -> q2_Query] := 
  Function[assoc, assoc[[Sequence @@ q1]] = q2@assoc; assoc, HoldAll];

MyReplacePartFix[ls_List] := 
  Function[assoc, Scan[(MyReplacePartFix[#]@assoc) &]@ls; assoc, 
   HoldAll];
```

Consequently, I see `Dataset`/`Association`'s value stemming from its ability to combine immutable/mutable approaches - the former to perform the familiar tinkering, experimenting, prototyping and the latter to bed down any findings/breakthroughs by recording incremental improvement in those computational units of special utility or interest.

Let's flog this example one more time to envisage a possible workflow that combines both approaches:

**A Toy Workflow**

The OP mentioned in a comment that his real point of interest was to record an integer's size relative to 5 which can be cast as a `Query`:

```
MoreThan5Query = Query[All, MapAt[Function[dummy, #"firstValue" > 5], "isGreaterThan5"]@# &];
```

Let us suppose that we would like to record an application of this query together with the earlier truth/table data. Hence we restore the original `xx`, generate data for `MoreThan5Query` and use `Dataset` to illustrate

```
Restore@xx;
yy = Association["firstValue" -> #[[1]], "isGreaterThan5" -> #[[2]]] & /@ Thread[{RandomInteger[10, 4], ConstantArray["?", 4]}];
datasetShow = Map[Dataset, #, {0, 1}] &;
Row[{
   <| "Truth" -> xx, "Size" -> yy|>, " -> ",
   <| "Truth" -> QueryMapAt@xx, "Size" -> MoreThan5Query@yy|> // (base = #) &
   }
  ] // MapAt[datasetShow, {{1, 1}, {1, 3}}]
```

[image]

The second dataset contains the second column's agreement and for the toy's sake we'll assume that it represents a relatively stable data structure worthy of recording - as indicated by assigning it to a `base` variable. Suppose in addition, that after a period of time, the first columns of `base` need adjusting but also to remain in agreement with the second column - hence the previous queries need to be-run. But this is where we get the payoff from the previous casting in this new context.

```
{C1QueryT, C2QueryT} = Prepend["Truth"] /@ {C1Query, C2Query};
 C1QueryS = Prepend["Size"]@C1Query;
```

Now suppose the adjustment involved negating the Boolean "firstvalue"s and adding 3 to the numerical "firstvalues. The adjustment can be initially performed before the corresponding agreement with the second column is readily re-implemented.

```
Row[
  {
   MyReplacePartFix[
     {
      C1QueryT -> (Not /@ C1QueryT@base),
      C1QueryS -> 2 + C1QueryS@base
      }]@base,
   " -> ",
   MyReplacePartFix[
     {
      C2QueryT -> C1QueryT,
      Query["Size"] -> MoreThan5Query[Query["Size"]@base]
      }]@base
   }
  ] // MapAt[datasetShow, {{1, 1}, {1, 3}}]
```

[image]

A native extension of `ReplacePart`/`ReplacePartFix` or equivalent would naturally make this more efficient (and the use of the inner base could be removed) and in more realistic examples would also involve at this step, (hopefully) high-level implementations of version control and unit tests, but taken together they form a powerful way of building on the language's immutable character.

As rightly pointed by @Murta in the comments of a previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56009/learning-resources-for-data-science-in-the-wolfram-language) seeking to summarise cheat-sheet learning pathway for data science functionality, one glaring omission was coverage of methods for their (mutably) modification. This functionality will hopefully now rapidly mature (it would also be useful exercise to collate the above into a complementary cheat sheet on `List/Association/Dataset` modifications).

**A final note on mutability/immutability**

The Mutability/Immutability dichotomy emphasised on StackExchange (largely contributed by Leonid Shifrin) is particularly interesting since viewed on a broader level I think it captures opposing/complementary forces that in many ways define scientific progress - experimentation and accumulation.

The Wolfram Language has long been an extremely powerful experimental platform by facilitating rapid algorithmic (and interface) prototyping. This is due in no small part to the language's immutability and all the accompanying well-documented advantages - advantages, happily, that have been continued with the recent datasets/associations additions. Following experimentation and/or prototyping however, there comes a point where one needs to play computational favourites and/or aim to permanently classify - to pick out those experiments (structures) worth recording and it is here I'd argue that a mutability idiom becomes the more natural approach - the ability to seamlessly augment a fixed structure.

In my view Mathematica has been less than stellar in accommodating mutable idioms which is also connected with it hitherto being [inadvisable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15627/is-learning-to-use-mathematica-useful-for-pure-theoretical-research-in-mathemati/15753#15753) to use it as a platform for storing/publishing computational research. The absence of this capability also lurks behind previous, countless questions on emulations of structs/object-orientation/databases and the [frustration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37888/is-mathematica-comparable-to-c-for-creating-standalone-applications/37911#37911) expressed about building sophisticated and rich interfaces beyond the complexity of `Manipulate`s.

My hunch however, is that this is all set to change followng`Dataset`/`Association`'s introduction since, while maintaining the familiar ability to integrate an immutable programming model, there remains the potential to incorporate mutable idioms (as it relates to the ways code is conceived and perceived - since, as pointed out, true general reference/ pointer semantics are not in place).

This is reflected initially, in the almost exclusive use `Part` to express mutability, in `ReplacePartFix` above, in  and in many other StackExchange questions (including speculation about high-level front-end editing of `Dataset`/`Association`s).

I have re-visited several old dynamic interfaces originally abandoned as they sank in a spirit-sapping morass of complexity. What I have found quite remarkable is how re-implemented within a (base) `Association`, their growth is not merely more amenable but actually becomes feasible - the addition of the 100th feature now roughly the same level of difficulty as adding the 1st.

Consequently, rather than view mutability as a poor cousin to immutability I see it as a rich uncle needed at a different (concluding) stage of development/experimentation. In fact, I'd anticipate an environment allowing seamless switching between the two as being especially powerful with far-reaching ramifications.

Language has an uncanny knack of hiding things in plain sight and the point expressed here appears in the descriptors *dataset* vs *database*. The *set* embodies the familiar (list) immutable approach whereas the *base* in database connotes a more fixed structure with a notional fixed address that one typically wants to modify "in-place" (and whose file-backed manifestations will IMO really see data science in Mathematica come into its own).

In life, this balance between fixed knowledge and its growth manifests in our DNA's *base* pairs representing the fixed knowledge of stored data and/or algorithms (protein-making instructions) with the spark plugs of its autonomous experimental engine, *mutation*. After performing its experimentation in the environment there comes a point where those favoured, self-perpetuating genes, need to be selected and added to the base genome. Hence, in this case the DNA takes the form of a *mutable* data structure (that is, with DNA considered at the species level - at the individual level DNA is more akin to an *immutable* structure with sufficient mutation (or re-combination) defining new identities)

This dance between fixed knowledge and its experimental expansion plays out in deeper, analogous ways in both DNA evolution and scientific progress but that is another story.