# Assigning new value in association

Tags: associations

I experienced a problem in changing values in an association and broke down the problem to the following: Given a list of association (here with one element):

```
temp = {<|"name" -> "Peter", "Punkte" -> 10, "Gender" -> "nn"|>}
```

then the following does not work:

```
temp[[1]]["Gender"] = "M"
```

but

```
assoc = temp[[1]]
```

and

```
assoc["Gender"] = "M"
```

works fine. I do not understand why?

Comment: I have covered exactly this case in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55494/changing-values-in-an-association-using-map/55503#55503), towards the end of the section named "Complications". What works is `temp[[1]][[Key["Gender"]]] = "M"` (apart from suggestions from other answers, but I believe my suggestion is closer to your original attempt).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you try `temp[[1]]["Gender"] = "M"` you get a warning message:

> Association::setps: <|name->Peter,Punkte->10,Gender->nn|> in the part
>   assignment is not a symbol. >>

This is telling you that the syntax `assoc[key] = value` is only valid if `assoc` is a symbol. You get the same warning if you try `<|a -> 1|>[a] = 2`

The simplest solution is to use the `Part` syntax for changing the value:

```
temp[[1, "Gender"]] = "M"
(* "M" *)

temp   
(* {<|"name" -> "Peter", "Punkte" -> 10, "Gender" -> "M"|>}
```