# Need explanation on strange behavior of Do together with AppendTo

Tags: replacement, assignment

We didn't expect a replacement of B.

```
In[1]:= A = {B};
f[x_, y_] := AppendTo[A, {x, y}];
Do[Print[f @@ B], {B, {{X, Y}}}];
A

During evaluation of In[1]:= {{X,Y},{X,Y}}

Out[4]= {{X, Y}, {X, Y}}
```

Comment: I thought B in the loop Do should be treated as a dummy variable.

Comment: Also interesting: `Table[{A, B}, {B, {{X, Y}}}]` gives `{{{{X, Y}}, {X, Y}}}`, but at least in this case, afterwards, `A` is still `{B}`. I think fundamentally, this is due to `Do` and `Table` using `Block` for variable localisation, which uses dynamic scoping. There's a [great answer of Leonid's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/2305) on what that means, but it's quite interesting that the `B` inside `A` actually gets evaluated in the course of the `AppendTo`. That's certainly somewhat unexpected.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `AppendTo`, you can see the same behavior in `A = {B};
Do[Print@A, {B, 2}];`

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yep, Do / Details-> Do effectively uses Block to localize values or variables..

Comment: @JasonB In that case, you still have `A == {B}` *after* the `Do` though, whereas in the OPs case, there is no `B` left in `A` after the loop.

Comment: That seems expected, since `AppendTo` redefines its first argument, exactly as if you said `Do[A = Append[A, B], {B, {1}}];`

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to use lexical ([`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)) scoping to localize `B` for `Do` in addition to the dynamic scoping that `Do` already has.

```
Module[{B}, Do[f @@ B, {B, {{X, Y}}}]];
```

In short, `Do` does scoping by temporarily changing the value of `B`.  This `B` is however still the very same symbol both inside and outside of `Do`, it just has a different value inside of `Do`.

`Module` will effectively cause `B` to become a distinct symbol, different from the one stored in the list `A`.  It achieves this by renaming it.

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend reading [Leonid's amazing answer about scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/2305). It explains very clearly what the difference between lexical and dynamic scoping is.

The docs say the following about `Do`:

> `Do` effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables.

That means `Do` uses dynamic scoping. That is, during the execution of the `Do` iteration, `B` *has* the value `{X, Y}` even if it doesn't appear explicitly in the loop. This doesn't quite explain yet why the value of `B` inside `A` is still changed after the loop though.

Compare your code:

```
Do[Print[f @@ B], {B, {{X, Y}}}];
(* {{X, Y}, {X, Y}} *)
A
(* {{X, Y}, {X, Y}} *)
```

To the following:

```
Do[Print[A], {B, {{X, Y}}}];
(* {{X, Y}} *)
A
(* {B} *)
```

The latter isn't too unexpected. When evaluating `A` for the `Print`, `B` has its local value so `A` evaluates to `{{X, Y}}` as expected. And afterwards `B` is undefined again (and `A` was never changed), so `A` reverts to `{B}`.

However, in your code, the `B` inside `A` is irretrievably lost. This is because `AppendTo` doesn't actually *modify* its first parameter in-place (leaving existing elements untouched), but actually returns a new list and replaces its first parameter with that. This is because lists are [immutable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55503/2305). But to do so, `AppendTo` needs to evaluate `A`. You can think of `AppendTo[A, x]` as being defined like this:

```
A = Append[A, x]
```

That means, the `A` on the right-hand side gets evaluated. At this point, `B` has its value of `{X, Y}` and hence is part of the result of `Append` and is now stored in `A`.

---

<s>I don't know if there's a viable workaround using `Do` which is safe regardless of which variables you've used before.</s> (There is, see Szabolcs's nice answer.) Of course, `Do` is generally frowned upon though, and a better option would be to use a functional style using something like `Scan` which avoids the need for a named variable altogether:

```
Scan[AppendTo[A, #] &, {{X, Y}}]
```

Or better yet, also avoid the side effect:

```
A = Fold[Append[#, #2] &, A, {{X, Y}}]
```

(Of course, for this simple case, a simple `A = Join[A, {{X, Y}}]` would do, but I'm assuming your actual code has a somewhat more elaborate update function.)