# Marking certain detected points on an image

Tags: image

I have an image in which I had to detect bifurcation points of vessels. I manage to do that and now I have an image where these bifurcation points are 1 while all others are zero.

What I want to is to place a green star at the bifurcation points on the original image. How can i do that? I am new to mathematica. So a code snippet would go a long way. Thank you.

Comment: Without the image and more details you will not get any answer I'm afraid. Would be great to share some code if you tried :)

Comment: Sounds like a duplication of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/labelling-objects-in-a-picture-with-numbers