# What are quick references to mathematica that fit my needs?

Tags: reference-request, education

I have read [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/733/what-is-the-best-mathematica-tutorial-for-young-people) but I think mine is different because they're searching for a way to learn mathematica comprehensively and basically but I'm searching for just some quick way that is enough for my needs.

I am totally new to `Mathematica` but I know `MATLAB` very well and I am familiar with `C++` programming and $LaTeX$
I just want to use mathematica as a calculating tool when I'm reading papers and **not as a programming language**. I've chosen `Mathematica` because of its full support of symbolic math.
I want to be able to study multivariable calculus, statistics and linear algebra by mathematica (you now mathematical concepts related to electromagnetism) and be fast in my calculations.

I have put some of my calculations done on `Wolfram|Alpha` here to specify my purpose more clearly.

[Partial derivation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdxdy%20xcos%202y%2Bye%5E%282x%29)
[Multiple Integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20x%20dy%20dx%2C%20y%3Dx%20to%202-x%5E2%2C%20x%3D-2%20to%201)
[curvature](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=curvature%20of%20x%28t%29%3Dcos%5E3%20t%2C%20y%28t%29%3Dsin%5E3%20t)
[ordinary differential equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3y%27%27%27%2Bx%5E2y%27%27-2xy%27%2B2y%3D2x%5E4&lk=4&num=1)
[Bessel function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20J2%28x%29&lk=3)
[integrate bessel function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E3%20J0%28x%29)
[Inverse laplace transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20laplace%20transform%20%283s%5E2-8s%2B3%29%2F%28s%5E3-4s%5E2%2B3s%29)
[Matrix diagonalization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%7B%7B1%2C1%2Bi%2C2%2Bi%7D%2C%7B1-i%2C2%2C3%2Bi%7D%2C%7B2-i%2C3-i%2C3%7D%7D)
[quadratic surfaces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2%2B2y%5E2%2B3z%5E2%2B2xy%2B4xz%2B6yz%2Bx-y-z%2B4%3D0)

I want to use `Mathematica` just as I use `Wolfram|Alpha`, as a calculator. But because of several reasons I don't want to use `Wolfram|Alpha` anymore and switch to `Mathematica` including:

1. I'd rather use a software rather than an online website and store
   the results
2. Maybe in the future, I will start to learn Mathematica
   comprehensively

What are the quick resources that I can master in just a day or two that fit my needs?

Comment: @blochwave I have explained at the top why I think mine is different. They're searching to expand their knowledge or teach mathematica efficiently but I'm just searching for something that fits my needs and is enough for a quick start and do your job

Comment: This is my favorite http://hyperpolyglot.org/computer-algebra

Answer (score 6):

On the home page of the *Documentation Center*, in the lower left-hand corner, there is a label that says "Common How Tos", Do a mouse-over on it; it will turn red, showing that it is a link. Double-click on it and you will taken to a portal to many of the tutorials contained the documentation, including links to "Do Calculus" and "Work with Differential Equations" found under the topic "Mathematica and Algorithms". You definitely want to follow those links. I think you will also want to follow a lot of other links you find by opening this portal.

Comment: I'm in the [home page of the documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) but I don't see such a thing like **"Common How Tos"** in the lower left-hand corner

Comment: If you can't find the _Common How Tos_ on the start/home page of the _Wolfram Documentation_ in  _Mathematica_ (I _can_ see it), go to the _Help_ menu and select _Find Selected Function_, then enter _guide/HowToTopics_.

Comment: @zentient ok i did what you said and found `HowTos` but do you really see **"Common How Tos"** in [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) where? I even searched `"common"` in the page but I couldn't find. Can you show me a photo?

Comment: @sepideh the link is in the home page of the built-in documentation (i.e. what you get if you press F1 in *Mathematica*) but not on the web page.

Comment: Simon Woods is correct. Click Help in the Menu Bar and then select the first row **Wolfram Documentation**. This looks similar to the web page but does have *Common How Tos* on the bottom left. The documentation is super excellent. For example type `Integrate`, select by double clicking and hit F1. It takes you to the help page, shows basic examples and has Tutorials, See Also and Related Guids on the upper left hand of the page.

Answer (score 5):

You first need to familiarize yourself with the syntax and general structure of the Wolfram Language, which Mathematica uses. As a form of introduction you could look at a few Wolfram introductory screencasts, for instance:

- [Hands-on Start to Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/handsonstart/)
- [Functional Programming: Quick Start](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/dev001.html)

Once you have done that, dive straight into the [extensive documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav) and play around with a few of the examples shown there. You could start with a few of the obvious commands, e.g. `Integrate`.

---

Having said that, I would still urge you to take the time to familiarize yourself with the basics as a first step. How long did it take you to become conversant in C++ or Matlab? I would wager that it was longer than "a day or two"...

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Maybe in the future I will have more time to start mathematica but currently I am working on my thesis and I want to quickly learn some of the basics of the tools to be able to use them

Comment: Link has changed: [Introduction to Functional Programming](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=101&v=491)

Answer (score 3):

Read some of the sections at 
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html
Also, avoid functional programming until you are familiar with the basics.