# Practice notebook for Pure Functions & Rules-Patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule, pure-function

Are there practice notebooks or exercises for practising using pure functions and rule-patterns?

I've completed "An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language" and "Fast Introduction for Programmers" but there were some examples missing for things like sequential slot (##1) or more complex combinations of using pure functions with rule-patterns.

I've taken a look at "Wolfram Programming Cloud" but the examples there are more to do with practical examples using Wolfram functions and datasets.

Comment: I'm in the same boat but generically across the language.  I was thinking of a set of beginner/intermediate/advanced Q&A cue cards that used good SE questions and had links to the SE page for further info.

Comment: The [documentation for Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is quite good with respect to things like `##n` and `Attributes`. See the Generalizations and Extensions. For patterns, what Ted Eresk suggested is useful, but I also have to highly recommend looking at [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html). I use variants on `f[a:_Type:default]:=body` all the time. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-positional-or-named-optional-arguments) as an example of how this works.

Comment: Found https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259 and  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/733/what-is-the-best-mathematica-tutorial-for-young-people. Whilst great resources for learning, does  not contain practice .nb like "Elementary Introduction".

Answer (score 6):

Go [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html) and read the sections about HoldPattern, Repeated, Slot SlotSequence. Then near the bottom of that page read the part about Pattern Matching. You can get lots of practice by using the features in code you write.... try solving problems that interest you.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a more interactive practice like from "An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language" exercise section.